# EXECUTE sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server

i have a problem with EXECUTE sp_executesql  and stuck with it.
my query is as follows

> ```
>    DECLARE @TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(5)='#T'
>    DECLARE @TABLE_ID INTEGER=0
>    DECLARE @QRY NVARCHAR(MAX) =''
>    DECLARE @TABLE VARCHAR(3)
>  DECLARE CRSR_WAGES CURSOR FOR SELECT Code,Name , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY U_Prrty, DocEntry) Slno, COUNT(Code) OVER (PARTITION BY OBJECT) ColNos
>                                      FROM  [@CCS_WAGE] 
>                                      WHERE  U_DISPP = 'Y' AND U_DEDWT='E'                        
> OPEN CRSR_WAGES
> FETCH NEXT FROM CRSR_WAGES INTO @WAGECOD,@WAGE_DESC,@SI_NO,@COL_NOS
> WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
> BEGIN
>     SET @TABLE=@TABLE_NAME+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@TABLE_ID)
>     SELECT @TABLE AS 'TABLE'
>     SET @QRY='(SELECT empno, amt AS '+'['+@WAGE_DESC+']'
>     SET @QRY=@QRY+' INTO '+@TABLE
>     SET @QRY=@QRY+' FROM CCS_PYMONTHRESULT WHERE wgcod='''+@WAGECOD+''')'
>     SELECT @QRY
>     EXECUTE sp_executesql @QRY
>     SET @TABLE_ID=@TABLE_ID+1
>     DECLARE @STAR AS NVARCHAR(50)='SELECT * FROM ' + @TABLE
>     SELECT @STAR
>     EXECUTE sp_executesql @STAR
>     FETCH NEXT FROM CRSR_WAGES INTO @WAGECOD,@WAGE_DESC,@SI_NO,@COL_NOS                    
>         END
> CLOSE CRSR_WAGES
> DEALLOCATE CRSR_WAGES
> ```

---

but the problem is when execute this error message comes like this
Invalid object name '#T0'.
Invalid object name '#T1'.
Invalid object name '#T2'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the temporary tables that you are referencing exists, then your problem is session scope. Temporary tables marked with a single `#` are visible to the session that they are created in, they are also known as local temporary tables.

The problem that you have is that when you execute a piece of dynamic sql it runs in a new session - hence that session cannot see the temporary tables that you have created.

To fix the problem you could do one of 3 things:

- Create the temporary table within your dynamic sql
- Use a global temporary table using `##` as these are visible across all sessions
- Re-design your code to insert into a table variable and return that as an output parameter to `sp_executesql`

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Brownstone...i created ## table and the problem get solved.

Comment: one more doubt... as in my query my column name is dynamic and how can i choose that through a query..in this case i need second column of all ## tables

Comment: If you have the table name you could do something like SELECT name FROM tempdb.sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'table_name') AND column_id = 2;

Comment: A good alternative to temp table is defining it as CTE. It is very flexible and a great substitute for temp tables. Have you a look at the link below to see how to define CTE : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/265371/Common-Table-Expressions-CTE-in-SQL-SERVER-2008

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic SQL runs in the same session as the calling code. The issue is not session, but scope. Your dynamic SQL creates the temporary tables inside the `sp_executesql` call and thus the created #temp table is only visible within *that* `sp_executesql` call, as documented in MSDN:

> Temporary tables are automatically dropped when they go out of scope,
>   unless explicitly dropped by using DROP TABLE:
>
> - **A local temporary table created in a stored procedure is dropped
>     automatically when the stored procedure is finished**. The table can be
>     referenced by any nested stored procedures executed by the stored
>     procedure that created the table. The table cannot be referenced by
>     the process that called the stored procedure that created the table.
> - All other local temporary tables are dropped automatically at the end
>     of the current session.
> - Global temporary tables are automatically dropped when the session
>     that created the table ends and all other tasks have stopped
>     referencing them. The association between a task and a table is
>     maintained only for the life of a single Transact-SQL statement. This
>     means that a global temporary table is dropped at the completion of
>     the last Transact-SQL statement that was actively referencing the
>     table when the creating session ended.

So you need retain of the #temp table in a scope that covers both the creation and the use, for example (also fixed the SQL injection problems you had and pass `@WAGECODE` as a parameter):

```
SET @TABLE=@TABLE_NAME+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@TABLE_ID);
SET @QRY ='(SELECT empno, amt AS '+ QUOTENAME(@WAGE_DESC);
SET @QRY +=' INTO '+@TABLE;
SET @QRY +=' FROM CCS_PYMONTHRESULT WHERE wgcod=@WAGECOD)';
SET @QRY += '
          SELECT * FROM ' + @TABLE;
EXECUTE sp_executesql @QRY, N'@WAGECODE <typeof@wagecode>', @WAGECODE;
```

Needless to say, this is quite a unnecessary use of #temp tables, you could simple select the result you want and call ti a day, there is no need for #temp tables:

```
SET @QRY ='(SELECT empno, amt AS '+ QUOTENAME(@WAGE_DESC);
SET @QRY +=' FROM CCS_PYMONTHRESULT WHERE wgcod=@WAGECOD)';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @QRY, N'@WAGECODE <typeof@wagecode>', @WAGECODE;
```