# If sp_ExecuteSql creates a new session, how come I can access a local temp table created (prior to it's execution) outside of the dynamic SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, dynamic-sql, temporary-tables, session

If local temp tables are only available to the current session, and sp_ExecuteSql creates a new session to execute the dynamic SQL string passed into it, how can that dynamic SQL query access a temp table created in the session that executes sp_ExecuteSql.

In other words, why does this work:

```
SELECT 1 AS TestColumn
INTO #TestTempTable

DECLARE @DS NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * FROM #TestTempTable'
EXEC sp_EXECUTESQL @DS
```

Results:

[image: Temp Table Results from Dynamic SQL Select]

My understanding for the reason why I can't do the opposite (create the temp table in Dynamic SQL and then access it outside the dynamic SQL query in the executing session) is because sp_ExecuteSql executes under a new session.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [an answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/24006/144393) by [Remus Rusanu](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/708/remus-rusanu):

> Dynamic SQL runs in the same session as the calling code. The issue is
>   not session, but scope. Your dynamic SQL creates the temporary tables
>   inside the sp_executesql call and thus the created #temp table is only
>   visible within that sp_executesql call, as documented in MSDN:

You can validate that you are using the same session in the `sp_executesql`  call by running:

```
DECLARE @DS NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT @@SPID'
EXEC sp_EXECUTESQL @DS
```

Knowing that `sp_executesql` runs under a different scope but not a different session, adding information found in the [docs on temporary tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#temporary-tables):

> Temporary tables are automatically dropped when they go out of scope,
>   unless explicitly dropped by using DROP TABLE:

And that same source on the visibility of temporary tables:

> Local temporary tables are visible only in the current session

These differences in scope vs. session explain why you are able to access the temporary table from the `sp_executesql` call but not the other way around.